# Concurrency in spark aggregate method

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am a beginner in Spark and Map Reduce, As I understand the spark aggregate(ByKey) methods follow the map reduce pattern, I would like have someone to help me to confirm it is correct or not.

1. the first function argument "segFunc" takes the data for each key
   and is run in parallel for each key. It is like the map() in map
   reduce.
2. the second function argument "combFun" gathers the data
   for each key, even across the partitions, it is not run in parallel
   and the system guarantees the synchronization of this combine
   function among all keys. It is like the combiner() in map reduce.

Please correct me, thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows the map/reduce pattern but you got the map/reduce pattern wrong.

The first phase will run in parallel and will create a record for each key (these would be kept in memory or spilled to disk depending on available resources in Spark vs. saved to disk in Hadoop)

Then the next phase would (or at least can) also run in parallel - per key. the data that was created previously would be fetched and merged so data for each key would arrive at a single destination (reducer)

The fetch phase is called shuffling

combiner in Hadoop is performing reduce like behaviour and emitting partial results (toward a reducer) at the map phase

Comment: Thanks very much, @arnon, So the second phase to merge data for each key in map-reduce could run in parallel, then in the case of the "combFun" function argument for aggregateByKey method in spark, if I want to get a collection of all data, then I have to use synchronizedList instead of normal list, is it right ?

Comment: Thanks again Arnon, after reading some stuff I realize I mixed up the concept "combiner" and "combine() function", the combiner for each bucket(partition) can run in parallel, but the combiner runs combine() method once, same as mapper and reducer.

Comment: Back to my question, since the function argument runs only in its separate instance, nothing except the result will be shared among them, the function is thread safe, its synchronization is guaranteed.